# "Rephrased we might say that what is urges questions of ought."

Tags: meaning

I am just reading an article about technology in medicine. I encountered two sentences which I can not understand the meaning. I think that the second sentence is not truly written.

The sentences are:

> Technology has widely enhanced the possibilities of acting and producing which poses the question of how we ought to realise these possibilities. Rephrased we might say that what is urges questions of ought.

Comment: i'm having trouble figuring out what the article is trying to say, but what i think it means is that current possibilities raise questions of what could be. It is almost certainly grammatically incorrect. Could you give some more context (maybe link the article)?

Comment: It should be "...is not **correctly** written."

Answer (score 2):

They're not well-written, but they do make sense.

In the first one, "which" refers back to the whole of the previous clause. It is saying that

> [the fact that technology has widely enhanced the possibilities of acting and producing] poses the question ....

The second makes sense only if you realise that the word "ought" is mentioned rather than used. It says

> Rephrased we might say that what is (i.e. the existing state of affairs) urges questions of "ought" (i.e. questions about what ought to be done).